# Add label to image link

Tags: html, image, onclick

I have this HTML-snippet that opens a new window when the image is clicked:

`<img src="some_image.jpg" onclick="window.open(this.src)">`

It's great, but I would also like to add some text beneath the image on the child window describing it's content. Is it achievable to do within the same tag on the parent-window, like this (however this is not working)?:

`<img src="some_image.jpg" onclick="window.open(this.src).document.body.innerText='The image description'">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onClick to call a function, like this:

```
<img src="some_image.jpg" onclick="enlarge(this.src, 'The image description')">
```

Now here is the function:

```
function enlarge(theSrc, theTxt){
    var myWindow = window.open("", "BigWindow", "width=300,height=300");
    myWindow.document.write("<img src='"+ theSrc +"' /><p>"+ theTxt +"</p>");
    myWindow.document.close();
}
```

Comment: You need document.close too

Comment: Thanks, just added that.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is most like the one I ended up with, however I did `window.open()` without any arguments to get a clear new window to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```js
function pop(img) {
  var w=window.open('','popup','width='+img.width+',height='+img.height+50);
  if (w) {
    var html ='<div style="text-align:center">'+
              '<img src="'+img.src+'" alt="'+img.getAttribute('alt')+'" /><br>'+
              '<h1>'+img.getAttribute('alt')+'</h1></div>'; 
    w.document.write(html);
    w.document.close(); 
  }
}
```

using

```html
<img src="some_image.jpg" alt="This is a Moose" onclick="pop(this)" />
```